# jquery Auto-complete loads ASCII HTML Character Codes in to the Text Area

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery AutoComplete plugin.

I have the data which has special characters as **'/-&**

When user clicks the text area, the autocomplete drop down shows the data correctly
for example:

```
don't drink
```

When user selects the text (don't drink)

In my textarea it load the value as ASCII characters:

```
don&#39;t drink
```

How can I have the data to load as normal data.

This is my autocomplete code:

```
 var directions ="don't drink/ Once a Day/ Take More/ You'are Good";
 directions = directions.split("/");
 $("#TextArea").autocomplete(directions, {
                matchContains: true,
                minChars: 1
            });
```

Comment: Why not add your `directions` as an array for strings?

Comment: it doesn't matter. my concern is if the string contains a special character like' - % & how to have this string to load in text area as same instead of ASCII code

Comment: Those are encoded characters. You'll need to decode them. You can use `.html(encodedStr).text()` or `unescape(encodedStr)`.

Comment: Well no use. As i said my string is displayed correctly on the autocomplete dropdown section but once i select the string from the drop down. the selected string it stored in text area that is being shown in ASCII

Answer (score 0):

You can add `formatResult` to your autocomplete options specifying a function that decodes the result that's output to the text box.